# Convert VMWare image to Parallels

Tags: macos, parallels, vmdk

Is it possible to convert a VMWare image or the vmdk files to a Parallels VM without booting the image in VMWare and installing the transporter client.

I downloaded a virtual appliance running linux, and it seems to much work if I should have to boot it in VMWare player on a windows box in order to get it over to my Mac.

On the VMWare side things seems much easier with VMWare converter.

Maybe I should switch from Parallels to VMWare Fusion instead on the Mac...

Comment: or use http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Of course that's a solution, but why have two virtual server softwares when one should be enough .)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [roderick.triple-it.nl](http://www.roderick.triple-it.nl/blog/2009/04/02/vmware-parallels) and [virtualizationdaily.com](http://www.virtualizationdaily.com/archives/73_how-to-convert-a-vmware-virtual-appliance-to-work-with-parallels.html) you can use qemu to convert vmware images to parallels images.

1. install qemu, so you have access to qemu-img binary.

   sudo port install qemu
2. convert the vmdk to a raw hdd image

   qemu-img convert appliance-harddrive-name.vmdk -O raw appliance-harddrive-name-raw.hdd
3. create a custom linux parallel virtual machine with the .hdd as disk image.

that said, the reason i prefer vmware fusion is because i like being able to run all the vmware appliances without doing the above...

Comment: This is what I was looking for. And I agree converting is a hassle, but it is a little bit quicker on SSD disks at least.